# Javascript to read CSV and create two HTML tables

Tags: javascript, html

In below code I am trying to create two HTML dynamic tables, but it doesn't work.
One table with ID "Table" and another one with ID "Tabled".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function Upload() {
const columns = [0, 3] // represents allowed column 1 and 3 in index form
const dccolumns = [0, 3] // represents allowed column 1 and 3 in index form

var fileUpload = document.getElementById("fileUpload");
var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.csv|.txt)$/;
if (regex.test(fileUpload.value.toLowerCase())) {
    if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            
            var table = document.createElement("table");
            table.id = 'table'
           
            var tabledc = document.createElement("tabled");
            tabled.id = 'tabled'
           
            var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");
            for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) { var cells = rows[i].split(","); if (cells.length > 1) {
                    var row = table.insertRow(-1);                        
                    for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
                        // ignore columns that are not allowed
                        if (!columns.includes(j)) {
                          continue
                        }

                        var rc = cells[j];
                        if (rc == "SUMMARY") {
                           var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                           cell.innerHTML = cells[j];                            
                           alert(rc);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            var dvCSV = document.getElementById("dvCSV");
            dvCSV.innerHTML = "";
            dvCSV.appendChild(table);

            var alld = document.getElementById("alld");
            alld.innerHTML = "";
            alld.appendChild(tabled);
    }
        reader.readAsText(fileUpload.files[0]);
    } else {
        alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
    }
} else {
    alert("Please upload a valid CSV file.");
}
```

}

When I run above code it just updates table in "Table", but not in "Tabled". I am not sure what wrong I am doing here.

Thanks

Comment: can you add HTM code here ? it hard to understand what is there in HTML

Comment: `document.createElement("tabled")` creates `<tabled></tabled>`

Comment: You got a typo for defining the variable `tabledc`. You write `var tabledc` but continue to use `tabled`. I guess that's just a copy and paste error. Please also provide the content of the csv file.

Comment: As Trevor Kropp mentioned, you create a `<tabled></tabled>` element which is not a table. But additionally you never seem to add any content to `tabled`, only to `table`. It may become clearer if you would use the devtools to debug your code and single-step through each line, monitoring its effects.

Comment: Thank you everyone. It has solved. How do I accept Trevors answer?